# In C language, Static Variable with pointer access

Tags: c, pointers, memory

My question is about Memory and how it is being accessed across a program with multiple C files (Multiple Modules).

file1.h Version 1

```
    #ifndef file1_h
    #define file1_h

    typedef struct
    {
      UINT8  var1;
      UINT16 var2;
      UINT16 var3;
    } TestAccess;

    static TestAccess* pLongRangeAccess;

    #endif
```

file1.h Version 2

```
    #ifndef file1_h
    #define file1_h

    typedef struct
    {
      UINT8  var1;
      UINT16 var2;
      UINT16 var3;
    } TestAccess_t;

    TestAccess_t* pLongRangeAccess;

    #endif
```

Main.c

```
#include "file1.h"

void main(void)
{
  pLongRangeAccess->var1 = 4;
  pLongRangeAccess->var2 = 8;
  pLongRangeAccess->var3 = 16;
}
```

Module1.c
//Needs read/write access to the struct variables

```
#include "file1.h"

void module1(void)
{
  pLongRangeAccess->var1 = 5;
  pLongRangeAccess->var2 = 10;
  pLongRangeAccess->var3 = 20;
}
```

Question 1) See "Version1" Does static in keyword make it such that there will be only one copy in heap memory (uninitialized) and therefore only one address of the pointer variable OR would it create 2 static variables with different memory since the header is used in every module?

Question 2) see "Version 2" If static was not declared for the pointer variable, then it would still be in heap memory and there would be one UNIQUE address that could be used to accessed to read and write operations to the members?

Question 3) In version 2 of file1.h if the pointer was declared in Main.c, and the memory location was fixed i.e it was declared as a constant, would it be available for access from any module by de-referencing the memory address location?

Comment: You don't allocate memory anywhere so your questions don't make any sense.

Comment: I see 3 questions, this is broad.

Comment: You don't declare static variables in header files. And there is no heap memory anywhere in these pieces of code.

Comment: Overall, never declare any variables in header files. Very poor program design and tends to lead to all manner of linking problems.

Comment: None of these are on the "heap". And `static` means static storage duration and linkage, read it as a global that's private to the compilation unit. What you're probably looking for is `extern`

Comment: "therefore only one address of the pointer variable OR would it create 2 static variables with different memory",
 this look like a [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you are mixing up "memory allocation" with variable declaration and variable definition. I think what you want is to share a variable `pLongRangeAccess` among different translation units, such that it exists only once in your program. To do that, *declare* the variable in the header file, and define it once in a single c-file:

```
#ifndef file1_h
#define file1_h

typedef struct
{
  UINT8  var1;
  UINT16 var2;
  UINT16 var3;
} TestAccess;

extern TestAccess* pLongRangeAccess;

#endif
```

And then the `.c`-file:

```
// file1.c:
#include "file1.h"
TestAccess* pLongRangeAccess;
```

Note that keyword `static`, when applied to variables outside any function, means that this variable is private to the respective translation unit; this is mainly for information hiding and for avoiding unintended name clashes with other translation units (from different vendors, probably).

So, if you write

```
// file1.c
static TestAccess* pLongRangeAccess;

// file2.c
static TestAccess* pLongRangeAccess;
```

, then translation unit `file1` and `file2` both have their own private variable `pLingRangeAccess`, which is not visible to other translation units (regardless if any head file declares the variable as `extern`). The linker will not complain any "duplicate variable definition" in this case, as - as mentioned - the variables are private to their TU.

If you write, however, the following

```
// file1.c
TestAccess* pLongRangeAccess;

// file2.c
TestAccess* pLongRangeAccess;
```

, then both variables become visible to the other translation units, and the linker will complain that variable `pLongRangeAccess` is defined twice in your program, which is not allowed.

Comment: Its becoming clear now. I see you define it as a static in the file1.c file. Static would mean that this pointer variable will only be accessible by any functions inside file1.c only. will a similar syntax be required for any other file that needs to access pLongRangeAccess?